# Is it possible to limit mocked function calls count?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-models, mocking

I have encountered a problem when I write a unit test. This is a chunck from an unit test file:

```
main.obj = MainObj.objects.create(short_url="a1b2c3")

with unittest.mock.patch('prj.apps.app.models.base.generate_url_string', return_value="a1b2c3") as mocked_generate_url_string:
    obj.generate_short_url()
```

This is a chunk of code from the file 'prj.apps.app.models.base' (file which imports function 'generate_url_string' which is being mocked):

```
from ..utils import generate_url_string
.....................
def generate_short_url(self):
    short_url = generate_url_string()
    while MainObj.objects.filter(short_url=short_url).count():
        short_url = generate_url_string()

    return short_url
```

I want to show in the unit test that the function 'generate_short_url' doesn't return repeated values if some objects in the system have similar short_urls. I mocked 'generate_url_string' with predefined return result for this purpose.
The problem is that I couldn't limit number of calls of mocked function with this value, and as a result the code goes to an infinite loop.
I would like to call my function with predefined result ('a1b2c3') only once. After that I want function to work as usual. Something like this:

```
with unittest.mock.patch('prj.apps.app.models.base.generate_url_string', return_value="a1b2c3", times_to_call=1) as mocked_generate_url_string:
    obj.generate_short_url()
```

But I see no any attributes like 'times_to_call' in a mocking library.
Is there any way to handle that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a generator that first yields the fixed value, then yields the return value of the real function (which is passed as an argument to avoid calling the patched value).

```
def mocked(x):
    yield "a1b2c3"
    while True:
        yield x()
```

Then, use the generator as the side effect of the patched function.

```
with unittest.mock.patch(
       'prj.apps.app.models.base.generate_url_string',
       side_effect=mocked(prj.apps.app.models.base.generate_url_string)) as mocked_generate_url_string:
    obj.generate_short_url()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! The only thing I have changed is firstly import a function that being mocked from project and then patch it:

    from prj.apps.app.models.base import generate_url_string;
    with unittest.mock.patch(
       'prj.apps.app.models.base.generate_url_string',
       side_effect=mocked(generate_url_string)) as mocked_generate_url_string:
    obj.generate_short_url()